# Java: use generics as abstraction layer

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use generics as abstraction layer similar as Java collections. Here is a  simplified example: the class EmployeeRecord stores information about employee and class Table should be generic and able to store various type of data. The type is passed to `Table` as generics.
I've problem with pass calls to the stored, specific class.

What's wrong with call of method print()? 
How do I solve it?

```
class EmployeeRecord
{
  String name;

  EmployeeRecord( String name )
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  void print()
  {
    System.out.println( name );
  }
} 

class Table<Record>
{
  Record rec;

  void set( Record rec )
  {
    this.rec = rec;
  }

  void printAll()
  {
    rec.print(); // COMPILER ERROR
/*
Test.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    rec.print();
       ^
  symbol:   method print()
  location: variable rec of type Record
  where Record is a type-variable:
    Record extends Object declared in class Table
1 error
*/
  }
} 

public class Test
{
  public static void main( String[] argv )
  { 
    EmployeeRecord emp = new EmployeeRecord("John");
    Table<EmployeeRecord> tab = new Table<EmployeeRecord>();
    tab.set( emp );
    tab.printAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Record` is not a bounded generic, so the compiler treats it as type `Object`.

Comment: compiler doesn't understand what type Record can be, so its inferring it as Object type. and Object doesn't have any method called print()

Comment: To reduce your confusion, use `T` instance of `Record` in your Table class. T is not a class. It's a generic type.

Comment: I was confused because method set() works without bounded type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to create common interface which all your record classes is going to implement

```
interface Record{
    void print();
}
```

Then your `EmployeeRecord` class will look like this

```
class EmployeeRecord implements Record
{
    String name;

    EmployeeRecord( String name )
    {
       this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println( name );
    }
}
```

And your Table will look like this

```
class Table<T extends Record>
{
    T rec;

    void set( T rec )
    {
        this.rec = rec;
    }

    void printAll()
    {
       rec.print(); 
    }
}
```

Then you call this from main method like this

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         EmployeeRecord emp = new EmployeeRecord("John");
         Table<EmployeeRecord> tab = new Table<EmployeeRecord>();
         tab.set( emp );
         tab.printAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I haven't used interface, because method set() works without bounded type, it has confused me.

Comment: The solution with interface is very nice, but how to implement a method which creates elements, for example, when the table should be loaded from a file? Factory methods have to be static and it's not possible to include them within interface? (not until java 8)

Comment: you mean factory to create Table with different type?

Comment: no, I mean load() method of Table which loads records of type T from file, my problem is how to create new records in method of Table, something like: 
`T rec = new T();`

Answer (score 0):

Java compiles generics using type erasure. If the type is not bound, the compiler treats instances of the parameterized type as being an `Object` instance.

To solve that, you have to *bind* the type to some super-type having the desired method:

```
interface Record {
    ...
}

class Table<T extends Record> {
    ...
}
```

Once bound, the compiler know that you can call any method of `Record` on an instance of type `T`.

In addition, it will reject any attempt to instantiate a `Table` with a parameterized type that is *not* a sub-class of `Record`. Whereas, in your original code, your `Table` object may be instantiated with *any* type parameter (which was probably *not* the desired behavior).